# Convert BLOB of a image to a image file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, blob, node.js-fs

I am working on a api that fetches the image from the server and it is giving the image as blob and now i wanted to convert that blob to a image file and save locally

I had tried to convert the image to base64 and then convert it to image and also tried some stackoverflow fixes but none of them worked

Here is the code

```
async function query(data) {
  var url;
  url = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/prompthero/openjourney";

  try {
    const response = await request(
      {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: url,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'AUTHTOKEN-HERE!!!',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      }
    );
    const result = await response.blob();
    console.log(result)
    return result;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("error occured");
    console.log(err)
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @LinDu Added the code i am fetching the data from hugging face api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we can download the image file.

```
import fs from 'fs';

async function query(data) {
  var url;
  url = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/prompthero/openjourney";

  const response = await fetch(
        url,
        {
            headers: { Authorization: "TOKEN HERE !!!" },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }
    );
    const result = await response.blob();
    return result;
}

query({"inputs": "Astronaut riding a horse"}).then(async (response) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('downloaded_image.jpg', Buffer.from(await response.arrayBuffer()));
  console.log('Image downloaded successfully.');
});
```

You can add up the error handling logics but this above logic will download the image.